# reference between slides in Beamr

Tags: latex, beamer, cross-reference

I have a code as below. I would like to create `\ref{}` between `item 1` in the second and third slides. So whenever someone clicks  `item1` in the second slide jumps to the third slide and vice versa.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\title{Main Title} 
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University A}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First Page}
        \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
            This is an example which will be used later.
        \end{exampleblock}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[label={important}]
        \frametitle{Second Page}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Third Page}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\title{Main Title} 
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University A}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First Page}
        \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
            This is an example which will be used later.
        \end{exampleblock}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[label={important}]
        \frametitle{Second Page}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \hyperlink{foo}{Item 1}
            \item Item 2 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[label={foo}]
        \frametitle{Third Page}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item \hyperlink{important}{Item 1}
        \item Item 2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SeymaKalay You're welcome! Have fun with beamer!