# hyperlink specific item/ after pause in beamer

Tags: hyperlink, latex, beamer, cross-reference

this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71172611/reference-between-slides-in-beamr) works perfectly, until I insert a `\pause`. I need to click enter to see where I hyperlink. Is there any way to get around with this?

```
    \documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\title{Main Title} 
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University A}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First Page}
        \begin{exampleblock}{Example}
            This is an example which will be used later.
        \end{exampleblock}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[label={important}]
        \frametitle{Second Page}
        \begin{itemize}
            
            \item Item 1
            \pause
            \item \hyperlink{foo}{Item 2}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[label={foo}]
        \frametitle{Third Page}
        \begin{itemize}
            
            \item Item 1
            \pause
            \item \hyperlink{important}{Item 2}
            \item \hyperlink{important}{Item 3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use pause? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: without \pause it works, but I want to use it with \pause if it is possible?

Comment: Do you want the hyperlink to jump to the slide with item 2?

Comment: yes, i want to jump back and forward from item 2 to item 2, while keeping the \pause.

Comment: Ah, I think I now understand the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the syntax `\hyperlink{important<2>}{Item 2}` to jump to a specific overlay within the frame:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\title{Main Title} 
\author{Jane Doe}
\institute{University A}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[label={important}]
        \frametitle{Second Page}
        \begin{itemize}
            
            \item Item 1
            \pause
            \item \hyperlink{foo<2>}{Item 2}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}[label={foo}]
        \frametitle{Third Page}
        \begin{itemize}
            
            \item Item 1
            \pause
            \item \hyperlink{important<2>}{Item 2}
            \item \hyperlink{important}{Item 3}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```